# Getting gas stations from OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I downloaded data from OpenStreetMap with QGIS, and I need to get the gas stations. Can you tell me what labels tell if something is a gas station?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found: amenity=fuel

The easiest way I found to do this, is to

- Go to https://www.openstreetmap.org
- Go to a gas station you know of
- Query it using the ? tool on the right.

Comment: Or just perform a search at the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page).